# JFrame scaling in Java 9

Tags: java, swing, java-9

Exactly the same code running under Java 9u4 on the left and 8u144 on the right on Windows 7.

[image: different window sizes]

Java 9 seems to making the window larger. What is causing this - JEP 263? How can I disable it?

```
public class SimpleFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Horse"));
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display/1207925#1207925). might be just the scaling

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thanks, unfortunately our lovely IT department have disabled such magic.

Comment: Similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613006/how-to-disable-scaling-the-ui-on-windows-for-java-9-applications

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this obscure option in a [substance bug report](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/substance/issues/48). This fixes the issue for Swing applications.

`-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0`

If you're using JavaFX you'll need

`-Dprism.allowhidpi=false`

Unfortunately I cannot find official documentation for either of these options

Comment: Could you clarify if that option is there by default and if so, what the value is?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I would do if I could find any official documentation on it :)